# Is the power set of a set a definable set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given some base set $A$, I'd like to know if its $k$-power set $\mathcal{P}_k(A):=\{S\subseteq A\mid |S|\leq k\}$ is a definable set in the first order language.

More specifically, is there a say $k$-ary relation $R$ defined by some first order formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}_k(A)$?

Comment: Which "the first order language" do you mean? The first order language of set theory?

Comment: Let's say it's first order logic symbols, and a unary predicate $p(x)=x\in A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal P_k(A)$ is the unique set $X$ satisfying the following formula:

$$
(\forall Y)((Y\in X) \Leftrightarrow (\exists Z_1,\dots,Z_k\in Y)(Z\in Y\Rightarrow ((Z=Z_1)\vee \dots \vee (Z=Z_k))))
$$

In other words, the elements of $X$ are precisely those sets $Y$ for which we can find $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$ such that every element of $Y$ is one of the $Z_i$.

Using the axioms of power set and separation, a set satisfying this formula can be shown to exist.

Note that this does not work if $Y$ is empty, but it is easy enough to deal with that special case.